# Panel Unit root in the presence of cross sectional dependence using pCADFtest

Tags: r

I want to use the pCADFtest in R but this is the response I keep on getting:

> Error in pCADFtest(data): could not find function "pCADFtest".

I need help on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error means you haven't loaded the package from which the pCADFtest function is obtained. The package is punitroot.

Load it using:

library(punitroot)